# UIView getting disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uiview

I have a `UIView` that's starting about 600 pt's off the screen, but when it comes on to the actual frame, it seems to be disabled.

I've tried using a `UIScrollView`, but also can't because I need to access the `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods form my `UIView`, so how would I enable interaction after it comes back on to the screen.

And yes I have tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`

Comment: Could you be more precise? Is this the only view added (maybe it's behind another one)? How does it "come" on to the actual frame? How do you know it actually "comes"? How would UIScrollView solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You would not have added this view to your main view that is why this can happen. If it is then ddont access it via `self.view` try to access with the view's name and this will start working.

Hope this helps.